# Pushing an entry to the start of an MSMQ

Tags: c#, windows, message-queue, msmq

Is it possible to send an entry to the start of an MSMQ? Instead of it always being in the tail, we would instead push it to the head?

Comment: Does [MessagePriority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310414/getting-message-by-priority-from-msmq) answer your question?

Comment: @HABO Yup it does. Do you want to make a question so I can accept it? I guess with priorities you can try to simulate this but you won't get the exact behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MSMQMessage.Priority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926410.aspx) to affect the order in which messages are processed from a message queue. Eight priority levels are supported.

A related SO question which discusses this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310414/getting-message-by-priority-from-msmq).